# Past Simple or Present Perfect: Tried or Have Tried

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I’ve tried to help you.

*The action happened in the past but I don’t say when.*

I tried to help you yesterday.

*The action happened in the past but I say when.*

1. Which is correct and which is not? I’m very confused!
2. Is there a simple rule to follow?

More Examples:

You can use the account that you’ve already created.

You can use the account that you already created.

I’ve sent you an email. Please check your Inbox.

I sent you an email. Please check your Inbox.

Comment: All are correct. With or without *have* all means same! Nevertheless, putting *have* in these sentences gives the flair of things being recently done (and not way back in past).

Comment: @Maulik Mostly right. But although linguists **have** been arguing about the perfect for 250 years, they generally agree it has nothing to do with recency.

Comment: @StoneyB Adding *been* would change it certainly. I **strictly** talked about the scenario mentioned by OP.

Comment: I think I feel perfectly fine to say *"I think I've sent you that email six months ago. Did you check your email carefully?"*

Comment: If you state a time period and that time period has finished, **you must use past simple**.

Comment: @Maulik *Argue* is an activity verb, atelic; it exhibits no semantic difference between simple and progressive constructions in a continuative perfect.

Comment: *I've tried to help you* implies you've tried to help them more than once, I think. (or could imply that) Whereas *I tried to help you yesterday* is much more specific and only refers to a single instance of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which sentence is incorrect will depend upon:

> 1. The country you are speaking the sentence in.
> 2. Signal words you are using in the sentence &

**In British English**, the use of Simple Past and Present Perfect is quite strict. **As soon as a time expression in the past is given, you have to use Simple Past**. However in American English, you can normally use Simple Past instead of Present Perfect, so the following rules rarely apply to American English.

**Signal words:**

If signal words explicitly define that the event is in past, you have to use **Simple Past**.

eg.

> 1. yesterday
> 2. ... ago (an year ago)
> 3. in 1990
> 4. the other day
> 5. last .. (last summer) etc.
>
> Example sentence: I phoned Mary 2 minutes ago.

If signal words do not explicitly define that the event is in past, you use **Present Perfect**.

> 1. just
> 2. already
> 3. up to now
> 4. until now / till now
> 5. ever
> 6. (not) yet
> 7. so far
> 8. lately / recently
>
> Example sentence: I have just called Mary.

[Source](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/simpas-preper) (Shamelessly copied word-to-word)